# Check if a field is final in java using reflection

Tags: java

I'm writing a class, which at some point has to have all its `Field`s assigned from another item of this class.

I did it through reflection:

```
for (Field f:pg.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    f.set(this, f.get(pg));
}
```

The problem is, that this class contains a `Field`, which is `final`. I could skip it by name, but to me that seems not elegant at all.

What's the best way to check if a `Field` is `final` in java using reflection?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The best and only one way is: `Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers())`

Reference:

- [`Field.getModifiers`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getModifiers%28%29)
- [`Modifier.isFinal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#isFinal%28int%29)

Comment: Not very `object oriented`. Curious to know the considerations of the API designers...

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka My guess: performance. The modifiers are likely implemented as bit-fields (with values, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 etc). The logic for this is in the `Modifier` class, it's the "single source of truth" for it. Since it's represented as an _integer_ in the `Field` itself, you cannot add methods to it (since primitives are non-inheritable in Java and most other programming languages).

Answer (score 8):

You can use `getModifiers()` method on the `Field` variable:

```
if ((f.getModifiers() & Modifier.FINAL) == Modifier.FINAL)
{
    //this is final field
}
```

Comment: Hi, I realise this an old post, but how does the if statement work here?  It's confusing me.  I would have assumed f.getModifiers() == Modifier.FINAL would have worked....

Comment: @AlanSmith `getModifiers` returns a bit-mask, with each individual set bit representing a particular modifier.  In order to check for one particular modifier, you need to check whether that particular bit is set - hence the bitwise 'and'.